# Can't get passed the welcome screen

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, boot, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a Acer Aspire 5553 Quad Core 64 bit Windows 7. I can boot Ubuntu 12.10 from a Live CD, but when I get to welcome screen (language choice,try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu). I have no response from the touch pad or the keyboard.

So can do nothing but power down and boot back to windows.

What's wrong?

Same problem applies to 12.10, 12.04. 64 and 32 bit

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try to plug an external mouse?

Comment: Try external USB mouse I had a similar problem a few versions ago.  I was able to fix the touch pad once Ubuntu was installed but needed a mouse to install.